# Evaluating the value of first derivative at $x=1$ for a polynomial $f$ satisfying $f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)=x^5+64$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial function such that $f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)=x^5+64$. Then, the value of $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x)}{x-1}$ is

$\boxed{A) \; -15}$

$B) \; -60$

$C) \; 60$

$D) \; 15$

I have solved it by considering a $5$ degree general polynomial of the form $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ and then algebraically solving to obtain the required result.

Is there any other method which doesn't include assumption of a function of any kind?

---

Source: JEE Mains 2022 25th June Shift-1

Comment: You are not *assuming* that it is a polynomial function; you are told that is what it is.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.sarthaks.com/3174496/let-f-x-be-a-polynomial-function-such-that-f-x-f-x-f-x-x-5-64-then-the-value-of-lim-x1-f-x-x-1) answer your question?

Comment: This question ignores the general solution of the given ODE as done by                @Claude Leibovici. In this light the question itself is not correct and out of the syllabus of IIT-JEE as this is a second order ODE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answer originates from [this page](https://www.sarthaks.com/3174496/let-f-x-be-a-polynomial-function-such-that-f-x-f-x-f-x-x-5-64-then-the-value-of-lim-x1-f-x-x-1) given by @DatBoi in the comments under the question.)
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{f(x)\over x-1}=f'(1) 
$$
(and $f(1)=0$)
$$
f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)=x^5+64\\
f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)=5x^4\\
f''(x)+f'''(x)+f^{iv}(x)=20x^3\\
f'''(x)+f^{iv}(x)+f^{v}(x)=60x^2\\
$$
so $$f^v(x)-f''(x)=60x^2-20x^3,$$ and
since $f(x)=x^5+\text{lower order terms}$, $$f^v(x)={d^5\over dx^5}x^5=5!=120$$ we have $f^v(1)=120$, so this becomes
$$120-f''(1)=40,$$ thus $f''(1)=80$. Since $$f(1)+f'(1)+f''(1)=65,$$ $f'(1)=-15$.

Comment: I am not able to see why $f^{v}(1)=120$ although I can observe that is true when $f^{iv}(1)=0$. So, ig my doubt would be that I am not able to find out this required value of $f^{iv}(1)$.

Comment: @Arsenic $${d^5\over dx^5}x^5=5!=120$$

Comment: How do you know that $f(1)=0$? (Without meta-reasoning of the form "if it were nonzero, then the limit would be infinite and so all the possible multiple-choice answers would be wrong")

Comment: @Micah I don't know, that assumption is used in the first equation too.

Comment: Thanks, got it now @SuzuHirose

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x) = x^5 + 64$$

Take the derivative.

$$f'(x) + f''(x) + f'''(x) = 5x^4$$

Subtract the two equations:

$$f(x) - f'''(x) = x^5 - 5x^4 + 64$$

Differentiate some more.

$$f'(x) - f''''(x) = 5x^4 - 20x^3$$
$$f''(x) - f'''''(x) = 20x^3 - 60x^2$$
$$f'''(x) - f''''''(x) = 60x^2 - 120x$$

Assuming that $f$ is a quintic, its sixth derivative is everywhere zero.  So the last equation is just $f'''(x) = 60x^2 - 120x$.  Substitute into a previous equation.

$$f(x) - (60x^2 - 120x) = x^5 - 5x^4 + 64$$
$$f(x) = x^5 - 5x^4 + 60x^2 - 120x + 64$$

So now we have an explicit formula for $f$.  To double-check, differentiate it twice.

$$f'(x) = 5x^4 - 20x^3 + 120x - 120$$
$$f''(x) = 20x^3 - 60x^2 + 120$$

And confirm that all the middle coefficients in $f + f' + f''$ cancel out, leaving you with $x^5 + 64$.

Now, $f(1) = 0$, so evaluating $\frac{f(x)}{x-1}$ directly at $x=1$ gives you the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$.  L'Hôpital's Rule applies.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{f(x)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{f'(x)}{1} = f'(1) = 5 - 20 + 120 - 120 = -15$$

QED

Comment: This seems to be correct, but this is about the same thing as doing it the original way of OP, by equating $a, b, c$ using derivatives.

Comment: Although, this does include determining the original function- the method is still useful to me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 6):

If you were not told that $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then you just need to solve the differential equation
$$f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)=x^5+64$$ With the usual method, the solution is
$$f(x)=e^{-x/2} \left(c_1 \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+c_2 \cos
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)\right)+ \left(x^5-5 x^4+60 x^2-120 x+64\right)$$ Differentiate and make $x=1$ to obtain
$$f'(1)=-15+\frac{\left(c_1\sqrt{3} -c_2\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\left(c_1+c_2\sqrt{3} \right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{e}}$$ and the result depends on the boundary conditions which fix the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: while correct, the question is about getting that particular solution!

Comment: @CalvinKhor. For sure, I assumed that the questioner knows how to solve a linear DE